# Why increasing NumPartitions while reading a file increases input size than the original file in spark RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I'm reading a small text file using `sc.textFile(<fileName>, 1)` with one partition, I can see input size is same as original file size.
However when increase the partition to 5. `sc.textFile(<fileName>, 5)` then the input size increased almost 3 times the original file size.
I'm calling count action to initiate job and code is running on my local machine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I expect there to be some minimum read size (block size), which is why your rather small file gets "overread"  (i.e. in theory each task would only need to read 3.7kb, but if the smallest block size is, for example, 8kb, then each task would have to read 8k). Have you checked if the effect is equally strong when your input file is much bigger? I suspect the effect will become smaller (in percents of the input) as  the input file size grows.

Comment: Thanks @JoachimSauer for getting back, I think you are right I tested for file size of 348.7 MB which created 11 partitions (as per 32MB block size). Then I read same file with 33 partitions and I can see input size is 350.5MB which pretty near to actual file size. The difference has gone down. For my earlier case even with block size of 8Kb it should ideally have ~41Kb input size, but it is showing 55.5Kb.hmm.. not sure what else is getting added.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, your file is tiny, and when you use bigger portions number, metadata show significant. If you try with larger files such as 1G or bigger, you see that metadata's overhead is nothing.